# Recompiling an old Fortran program and getting this error

Tags: compiler-construction, fortran, g77

The section of code looks like this;

```
DO i = 1 , no2 + 1
   IF ( Isign.EQ.1 ) THEN
      Ans(i) = fft(i)*Ans(i)/no2
   ELSEIF ( Isign.EQ.-1 ) THEN
      IF ( ABS(Ans(i)) .EQ. 0.0 )
&           PAUSE ' deconvolving at responce zero in convlv'
      Ans(i) =  fft(i)/Ans(i)/no2
   ELSE
```

The compiler is giving me this error;
    IF ( ABS(i)).EQ. 0.0)
         ^
    Type disagreement between expressions at (^) and (^)

```
IF ( ABS(i)).EQ. 0.0)
            ^
invalid form for IF statement at (^)
```

Can someone tell me how to write this "Intrisic function" line correctly to solve this error?
I am new to programing and any help would be great! I am using the GNU G77 compiler if
that matters?  Thanks

Comment: The compiler presumably gives you a line number for the error.  Is that line number one of the lines shown?  It's superficially similar to one of them.  If not, find the line with the error and fix it.

Answer (score 1):

I see more right brackets than left ones in the second error statement

```
IF ( ABS(i)).EQ. 0.0)
```

Also, what is the type and kind of Ans(i) and of 0.0? I remember fortran can be a bit strange about type conversions.

Comment: With the source code better displayed, we can now see that the parentheses balance.    Probably the answer is that array "Ans" has a type other than real, the type of "0.0".   Change the constant to be the same type as "Ans".   P.S.  Exact comparisons of floating point values are risky.

Comment: Could it also be same type, different kinds? I remember I had a lots of issues with that in subroutine calls.

Comment: Also it seems a bit strange that the compiler would replace `Ans(i)` with `i`. Are we really looking at the code snippet that causes the error?

Answer (score 0):

***Declarations, please. They make a world of difference!***

***Comparing something to a decimal zero is a very bad practice***. It
is almost always better to compare it to a value of tolerated error (which
should be made small enough).

With the above said, ***try writing a small compilable example which 
produces the same error and posting it.***